# Вывод валюты в определенном формате

Tags: c#

как я могу привести число например: 1450000 к строковому формату 1 450 000 или например 450000 к 450 000 ?

Comment: Форматирование вывода C#: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/7.5.php

Comment: Мне нужен формат описанный выше, я без понятия как его сделать по вашей ссылке

Comment: @Goga включите логику и все поймете.

Comment: @dmtr спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 1450000;

var nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("#,0", nfi));
```